# I have one table with winner_id and loser_id. I want to add columns winner_dob and loser_dob from another table which has different format

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, inner-join

I have one table (fme_fights, top image) with winner_id and loser_id. I want to add columns winner_dob and loser_dob from another table (fme_fighters, bottom image) which has different format.
[image: fme_fights]

[image: fme_fighters]

I have tried

```
update temp3 
left join temp4 on temp3.dob_w = temp4.dob
set temp3.dob_w = temp4.dob
where temp3.winner_id = temp4.id
```

This resulted in 0 rows affected

I have tried

```
INSERT INTO temp3(dob_w)
SELECT 
   dob
FROM 
   temp4
LEFT JOIN temp3
ON temp4.id = temp3.winner_id;
```

Before this I added a column to temp3 (dob_w) for the winner dob. There was no error, but the dob_w contained only null values

How can I add the dob for the winner_id and the loser_id?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you want two joins from the fights table to the fighters table:

```
select fs.*, frw.dob as winner_dob, frl.dob as loser_dob
from fme_fights fs
inner join fme_fighters frw on frw.fme_id = fs.winner_id
inner join fme_fighters frl on frw.fme_id = fs.loser_id
```

I would not recommend storing the date of births of the fighers in the fights table. This is derived information, that can easily be computed on the fly when needed, as showed in the above `select` statement. You can create a view if you are going to run this query often:

```
create view v_fme_fights
select fs.*, frw.dob as winner_dob, frl.dob as loser_dob
from fme_fights fs
inner join fme_fighters frw on frw.fme_id = fs.winner_id
inner join fme_fighters frl on frw.fme_id = fs.loser_id
```

If you insist on storing the data, then, assuming that you have created the two columns in the target table already, you need an `update` statement. In MySQL:

```
update fme_fights fs
inner join fme_fighters frw on frw.fme_id = fs.winner_id
inner join fme_fighters frl on frw.fme_id = fs.loser_id
set fs.winner_dob = frw.dob, fs.loser_dob = frl.dob
```

Comment: I'm curious. Is there a reason you don't recommend storing the dob in the fights table?